# Rails 3 - has_many through with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a nested form but keep getting this error when saving -

```
uninitialized constant User::Userplan
```

Here is my model code -

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :userplans
  has_many :plans, :through => :userplans
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :userplans
```

UserPlan

```
class UserPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :plan
 belongs_to :user
```

Plan

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :userplans
 has_many :users, :through => :userplans
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "user[userplans][plan_id]", 2 %>
 <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>
```

I know using a hidden_field_tag is wrong but im not sure of a better way

Thanks for any help!

activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:260:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:352:in`block in replace'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:352:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:352:in`replace'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/associations.rb:1524:in `block in collection_accessor_methods'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1559:in`block in attributes='
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1555:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1555:in`attributes='
cancan (1.4.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:72:in `build_resource'
cancan (1.4.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:48:in`load_resource_instance'
cancan (1.4.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:30:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.4.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:24:in`load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.4.1) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:9:in `block in add_before_filter'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in`*run*_3988671192319902872__process_action_*982103756142273942*_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in`process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in`dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in`block in action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in`block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in`optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.2) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in`block in call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in`cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in`_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in`call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`block in call'
:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in`call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in`call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in`service'
/Users/joshcrowder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/joshcrowder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in`run'
/Users/joshcrowder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is with the naming of your associations. Since your `UserPlan` model is CamelCased <- like that, Rails 'tabelizes' the name of it into `:user_plans`, not `:userplan`. Your error, as you can see, stems from Rails not being able to find `Userplan`, when it should be looking for `UserPlan`.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :user_plans
  has_many :plans, :through => :user_plans
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_plans
```

Plan:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_plans
  has_many :users, :through => :user_plans
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "user[user_plans][plan_id]", 2 %>
 <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>
```

With regards to the `hidden_field_tag`, what exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps you should open another question?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I made the changes and got this error - UserPlan(#2184506360) expected, got Array(#2151973780)

Comment: I have added it to my question

Comment: Tks...saved my life :)